# Show alert if style is not supported, without HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would need something like this:

```js
if {
  @supports not(display: grid) {
    window.alert("Please use a different browser.");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So if CSS grid is not supported by a browser, it should show a **JavaScript alert**. I know how it would work with just CSS, but I need a JavaScript or jQuery solution, without any HTML in the HTML section. How is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this too complicated

```
if (document.documentElement.style.grid === undefined) {
    alert("Please use a different browser.");
}
```

In modern browsers, `grid` is a property of the style of every element. If it's undefined, then the browser doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an element which is normally hidden, but becomes visible if grid is not supported. Please check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports

For example you have an element `warning-message` with `display: none;` and

```
@supports not (display: grid) {
  #warning-message {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. This is the way I know, but I would need a JavaScript window.alert instead, and I can't create a warning message in HTML for that.

Comment: Ah, my bad, then what @AngelPolitis posted would probably be what you're looking for.